# States of matter.Liquid

Tags: physical-chemistry

In a book a read that a simple defination of liquid i.e."it is a material that assumes the shape of a container without filling it completely" but i cannot able to understand  "without filling it completely".
please eleborate this ?

Comment: Presumably this is meant to distinguish liquids from gases, which both assumes the shape of the container and expands to fill the entire shape.

Comment: Along the same lines, the definition of gas would be a 'material which assumes the shape of container and fills it completely'.
These definitions are very much intuitive as a gas always fills the container in which it is put. 
The liquid on the other hand, does not fill the container.

Comment: @ShahMHasan As in my mind filling a container not depend the quantity of liquid that we put into container?

Comment: If a glass of water has 100 ml capacity and you pour in 50 ml, only half of the glass will be filled. The liquid does not expand to occupy the 100 ml.

Comment: @ShahMHasan  If the cpacity of glass 100ml .we pour also 100ml of liquid in it.then container is fully filled.then this situation not satisfy defination of liquid.

Comment: @user77330 The point is not whether the liquid actually fills the container if you add the exact amount: it is whether the liquid fills the container if you don't. Liquids have a defined volume: if you add less than the volume of the container, the container will not be full with liquid. The point being the volume of liquid doesn't depend on the volume of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both liquid and gas will assume the shape of the container.
It's also intrinsic for the gas to  fill up the volume of the container but such a feature is not intrinsic to the liquid. Therefore the book is implying that if the second feature does not imply, the phase of the matter in question is liquid.
please note:
Though we may fill up a container to it's volume by a liquid, this is us filling the container not the liquid intrinsically. Any volume of gas can fill up a whole container Intrinsically (Imagine the space).
Hope this helps abit.